# MissingRequiredArgument problems with discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been struggling to get this to work. what i am trying is to use discord.py
creating a command like this

```
browser_online = True

@client.command()

async def logout(ctx, *, browser_online):

browser_online = False

print(browser_online)
```

when i try it gives me an error saying `browser_online is an argument needed`.

i have tried to put it in `@client.command(browser_online)`

i tried to put it in the function like this: `async def logout(ctx, browser_online)`

nothing seems to work, pls help

Comment: How are you invoking the command?

Comment: sorry for my super low iq, but what do you mean by invoking? if you mean by calling it, i just go in discord and type the command

Comment: Yes.  The way the command is written, it's expecting you to pass `browser_online` as an argument when you call the command from discord: `!logout true` for example.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there a way to do it without adding True and it still gets it?

Comment: It should already be available without passing it at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use

Comment: alright, thanks for your help!